# how to identify labled contours at opencv

Tags: opencv

My attached code only identifies contour that are not labeled, performs only on 1 and zero labeled masks. My input mask images are actually labelled with 1,2,3,4.... of each contour. Example, first contour is labeled as 1, second is is labeled as 2, intead of only 1 for all contours. How can modify my code so I may be able to separate each contour separately base on the labeled image. Example contour1 a separate image, contour2 another separate image.

cvFindContours(maskImg, storage, &contours, sizeof(CvContour), CV_RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE, cvPoint(0, 0));

```
CvSeq *r;
int objectIndex = 0;
int fov = atoi(seriesName) + 1;
for(r = contours; r != NULL; r = r->h_next){
    /* Save each object in separate mask file. */

    /* Clear the mask object image buffer. */
    cvSet(objectMaskImg, cvScalarAll(0), NULL);
    /* Set the color of the external area and hole area of object. */
    CvScalar externalColor = cvScalarAll(0xff);
    CvScalar holeColor = cvScalarAll(0x00);
    /* Recognize child contour. */
    int maxLevel =  -1; 
    /* Fill interiors */
    int thinkness = CV_FILLED; 
    int lineType = 8; /* 8-connected */
    cvDrawContours(objectMaskImg, r, externalColor, holeColor, maxLevel, thinkness, lineType, cvPoint(0,0));
```

Comment: This program only indentifies contours of mask images 1.  The program that I need is to identify a separate mask images as input that will be labled 1,2,3..and create a new image with each labeled contours. Becuase the final output is based on each contour...

Comment: In summary: is there any opencv function that can separate conoturs base on labels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use a logical `AND` between your mask and the contours returned by FindContours? Or maybe I don't quite understand what you are doing.

Comment: I was actually planing to use only one set of masks, that has the labels on it, and separte them base on lables on it.  If I am correct as newbie, I may also loose data with AND.